# Can I print specifically what's wrong when parsing XML?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

This is sort of related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005664/flash-as3-display-an-error-if-the-xml-if-incorrect).  I'm creating an XML object within a try/catch block based on text returned from URLLoader.  When it's malformed, the catch runs and I can print a generic message but is there a way to print a specific message, like "no closing tag </foo>" or something like that?  Or does the assignment to an XML object just fail generically and there's no error message that I can retrieve?

If I copy/paste the text returned from URLLoader into the w3schools [validator](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_validator.asp), it uses javascript (DOMParser) to print a fairly decent message of where the error is.

```
var parser=new DOMParser();
var text=document.getElementById(txt).value;
var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length>0) {
   checkErrorXML(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror")[0]);
   alert(xt)
   }
else
   alert("No errors found");
```

It'd be nice if XML() set a system error or put it in the error object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, according to the AS3 docs there isn't the same support for error documentation in the AS3 XML parser as there is for the JS DOMParser.

as3 XML:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#XML()

DomParser:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser

Might be worth creating a ticket for this feature with Adobe: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform